# Acceleration of a merry-go-around, when a human is walking along it's rim

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotation, rigid-body-dynamics

*According to law of conservation of angular momentum, the merry-go-around is expected to rotate at constant angular velocity, while the man walks along it's rim with constant speed relatively to the merry-go-around. 
But I was thinking about it, and I noticed that each step the human takes produces a force which pushes the surface of the marry-go-around. Thus, it should revolve **faster and faster** with each step of the human. Am I right?*

Comment: What about the forces when the foot comes down?

Comment: I always thought, that we walk forward due to forward friction caused by backward push of our feet, and there is no forward push.
Ok, now I'm re-learning to walk, and this is what I notice: [link](http://pendulum.epizy.com/physics/walking.jpg). If I'm right, assuming the marry-go-around is not moving initially, when the human starts to walk, it should revolve, stop, revolve, stop, and so on until the human stops

Comment: however this would imply, that if I lean forwards (or backwards, but forwards is easier), then the merry-go-around would rotate faster and faster and faster and faster, because I'm pushing the merry-go-around (disc) backwards all the time

Comment: @DJohnM all this stuff sounds for me like lifting myself up by pulling my hair for my own :-)